# When doing @PutMapping, how is the data added without being initialized?

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js

When I update vue, I designed a database with a 1:n relationship so that a member can have multiple product. But when you update, what was there before disappears and only one new data remains. I want members to be able to have multiple product.

--springboot (controller)

```
@PutMapping(value = "/productSetting/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<User> updateUserProduct(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestBody Map<String, Object> data) {
    Optional<User> userData = userRepository.findById(id);
    Optional<ProductInfo> productInfo = productInfoRepository.findById(Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(data.get("id"))));

    ProductInfo realProductInfo = productInfo.get();
    if (userData.isPresent()) {
        User _user = userData.get();
        Set<ProductInfo> set = new HashSet<ProductInfo>();
        set.add(realProductInfo);
        _user.setProductInfo(set);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(userRepository.save(_user), HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

--vue.js (script)

```
updateUserProduct() {
  var data = {
    id:this.currentUser.id,
    productInfo: this.currentProductInfo,

  };
  ProductSettingDataService.update(this.currentUser.id, {id: this.currentProductInfo.id})
    .then(response => {
      this.currentUser = response.data;
      console.log(this.currentUser);
      console.log(status);
      this.message = 'update Success';
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
},
```

I think it's a problem with the controller, can you get help with which part of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Set<ProductInfo> set = new HashSet<ProductInfo>();
    set.add(realProductInfo);
    _user.setProductInfo(set); -- the problem is here
```

You are using one-to-many relation and when you do `_user.setProductionInfo(Collection)` you update the whole relation - all of the entries in collection are inserted\updated, and all of the old entries which belonged to user before and are not present in the collection are deleted.

To make it work as expected using one-to-many relation:

```
_user.getProductInfo().add(realProductInfo); // to Insert

_user.getProductInfo()   // to Update
.stream()
.filter(pi -> Objects.equals(pi.getId(), data.get("id"))
.findFirst()
.ifPresent(pi -> //update ProductInfo consumer);

userRepository.save(_user);
```

But why don't you consider updating the ProductInfo entity instead of user?

```
productInfoRepository.findByIdAndUserId(productInfoId, userId)
 .map(//set fields UnaryOpertor)
 .map(productInfoRepository::save)
 .map(ProductInfo::getUser) // You may need to select user from repo, depends on entities
 .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
 .orElseGet(() -> ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
```

Comment: Keep in mind that my snippets may cause stackoverflow exception in case you use bi-directional mappings.

Comment: When I tweaked it, it works the way I wanted it to. Thank you for your great help :)